# Data isn't stored properly from tempArray[] to realArray[][]

Tags: c++, loops, argument-passing

I have a file with one record per line (name, name, id#, grade, grade, grade, grade, grade, grade)
I have to validate according 64 digits or less : names, id:9 digits and 0 < grade < 100.
I want to store in tempArray[9], validate then store in realArray[9][200]. I think my MAIN problem is when I try to store.

tempArray was tested pretty much everywhere with `std::cerr << tempArray[i] <<std::endl;` and it contains proper data.

BUT realArray also was tested and contains only the first record. I am passing realArray to the following functions so that when I get to storeData, I can transfer tempArray to realArray, with column marker according to lineNumber.

I KNOW THERE ARE PROBABLY TONNS of errors and programming "DON'T Do's", but I need to know

1) if what I'm trying to do can be done
2)Why my realArray is only getting the first record.

/*Added After: I know that it's not being stored in realArray, because my increment variable is a `const int`. but then it doesn't make sense to me why it accepts to store the first record. is it because line Number is initialised to zero?
if storeData accepts lineeNumber the first time, why doesnt it do so for the second?*/

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "A4prototypes.h"
#include "search.h"
#include "sort.h"

using namespace std;


void getFile(std::string realArray[][200], const int ROWS)
{
std::string filename, line, token;

int row(0);                           
int lineNumber(0);
const int MAX_RECORDS (200);
const int TEMP_ROWS(9);
const int ZERO(0);
std::string tempArray[TEMP_ROWS];

std::cout << "Please enter the desired filename with it's extension:\t ";
std::cin  >> filename;

std::ifstream input(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);

if (input.is_open())
{   
    getline (input,line);                     

    while (input.good() && lineNumber < MAX_RECORDS)   
    {   
    std::istringstream inputss (line);    

        while (getline(inputss, token, ',') && row < ROWS )            
        {   
            tempArray[row] = token;                                     

            row++;
        }

        row = ZERO;

        /*I know I don't need to send the rows size of both of these arrays, but ... */

        validateData (lineNumber, tempArray, TEMP_ROWS, realArray, ROWS);  
        lineNumber++;

        getline (input,line);

    }
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "The file did not open correctly. \n\nPlease enter a valid filename.\n";
    }

    if (lineNumber == MAX_RECORDS)
    {
    std::cout << "The maximum number of records to be read (" << MAX_RECORDS << ") has been reached.\n";
}
}

void validateData (int lineNumber, std::string tempArray[], const int ROW, std::string realArray[][200], const int ROWS)
{       
    int j(0);

//Validate Data functions...


// Pass tempArray and realArray along with lineNumber to update realArray.

storeData(lineNumber, tempArray, ROW, realArray ,ROWS); 

}

int storeData(int record, std::string tempArray[], const int ROWS, std::string  realArray[][200], const int ROW_SIZE)
{
int k(0);

std::string tempstr;

record-=1;


for (k; k < ROWS; k++)
{
    tempstr = tempArray[k].data();

    realArray[k][record]=tempstr;
}

return 0;
}

int main ()
{
/* There should be a pointer here that gets sent to getFile and incriminates with the record line, gets sent to store data and the
rest instead of just lineNumber,????...*/

int i(0), j(0);           
const int ROWS(9);
const int COLUMNS(200);

/* int * const rows = &ROWS;  => It says in the book you can do this and pointer isn't const, but you could do *rows =10, which is what I want to 
do with the column, but it wont work... */

std::string realArray[ROWS][COLUMNS]={}; // Declare array for storing the data once it's been validated so I don't keep unecessary data.


 // Pass realArray to getFile so I can have access to it from main but it can be changed by getFile was the plan so fn's dont have to all be related to main.

getFile(realArray,ROWS); 



return 0;
}
```

And here's the header file

```
#ifndef _h
#define _h


void getFile(std::string [][200], const int);

void validateData (int,std::string [], const int, std::string [][200], const int);

int storeData(int, std::string [], const int, std::string [][200], const int);

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code "example" contains tons of code not directly contributing to the problem (why data doesn't end up in `realArray` as expected). Reducing the amount of code before posting would have given you valuable insight into which parts of code are *not* faulty, and possibly uncovered the bug before you even had to ask.

Even worse, you dumped 500 lines of code on us *and it does not even compile* (`FThis.h` is missing, copying the required function declarations into the example would have been trivial.)

And once I fixed the declarations and added `#include <stdlib.h>` so I don't get diagnostics about `atoi()` not being declared, I still get several warnings regarding stuff like this...

```
char letterGrade('NR'); // character constants may only have *one* character
```

...or this...

```
int i(0);
int numOfArrayBox(5);

// This is broken on several levels; chiefly, "i < NUM_OF_ASSIGNMENTS" will
// never terminate the loop as it is followed by a comma, the effect of which
// is apparently lost to you as you make this mistake in several places.
for (i, numOfArrayBox; i < NUM_OF_ASSIGNMENTS, numOfArrayBox < MAX_NUM_OF_ARRAY_BOX; i++, numOfArrayBox++)
```

Hint:

```
for ( int i = 0, int numOfArrayBox = 5; ( i < NUM_OF_ASSIGNMENTS ) && ( numOfArrayBox < MAX_NUM_OF_ARRAY_BOX ); ++i, ++numOfArrayBox )
```

...and at that point, I'm somewhat reluctant to spend more time debugging your code. Try [Machete Debuggung](http://dev.rootdirectory.de/trac.fcgi/wiki/MacheteDebugging) and [asking questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

But I have a general hint for you:

This is C++, not C. In C++, you don't use arrays of arrays, because you organize your code and data *object-oriented*.

Define a class (say, `class Student`), which contains the data (name, ID, grades), does the validation of data in the constructor, and also contains the functions to operate on that data (`sumOfAssignments()` etc.).

And when you need a collection of students, use `<vector>` instead of arrays:

```
#include <vector>

// ...
std::vector<Student> class;
Student input( "John", "Doe", 420012345, 64, 71, 89, 91, 88, 75 );
class.push_back( input );
```

Bottom line, your problem is not about `realArray` not containing the data you want, your problem is that you jumped into deep C++ water while still wearing (C) swimmies. Try reducing your example into something compiling without warnings and clearly exhibiting a single problem, and we will be able to give you a concise answer.

Comment: @Natlie: Yikes... you don't know why header files are necessary, but you're trying to get a non-trivial file data storage programm to run? Hmm... maybe you should reconsider your choice of learning material. (Header files provide function and variable declarations, so the compiler knows that e.g. `validateNames` is a function requiring three `int` as parameters and returning an `int` itself - *before* the function is called the first time.)

Comment: No, I know, Iknow . . . been up too long! that,  Sorry for seeming retarded. I actually get it more than i believe. . . whatever. PS It's a required course for civil engineering... and I'm one of the only one sin class who's actually trying to do it... I'm trying my best! @The rest, I edited code, took out useless fn' and put in my modified stuff. PPS There's also a prob with the while loop to get valid filename. if invalid is entered, loop doesn't stop!!! like as if ifstream won't change filename into the new input...?

Comment: The teacher actually asked us to have them in arrays. Was up all night trying to fix it. I will reedit posting to put what I finally handed in. It half works, I figured a lot of things out, such as: if I want to increment the value in 'COLUMNS', I have to give myself a pointer somewhere in 'main', when I declare realArray, or in 'getFile', and use it as the 'lineNumber' and pass THAT pointer to 'storeData' so that when I use it in "realArray[i][lineNumber], it actually increments. 'cause thats where the problem is...but I can't make a pointer say 'int' from a 'const int' that's what VS says.

Comment: Tell your teacher "hi" from me, and that he's making a real fine big mess of what should be a painless introduction into the beauty of programming. ;-)